# Get list of conda packages programmatically in Python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Is there a way to get all conda packages programmatically in Python?

Basically, I want to find the Python equivalent of running

```
conda list
```

Of course I could open a os subprocess and just call `conda list`, but I was hoping for a better solution than that.

Comment: Not currently, sorry. You'll need to use `os.system('conda list')` as stated. Seems a bit hackish, but it'll work :(

Answer (score 1):

One needs to have the `conda` Python package installed in the environment, which is usually only true for the **base** environment. One can then use the same code that `conda list` calls internally, namely, `list_packages` from the module `conda.cli.main_list`. For example, the following would be the equivalent to `conda list -n foo`:

```python
import conda.gateways.logging
from conda.cli.main_list import list_packages
from conda.common.compat import text_type

prefix = "/path/to/miniconda3/envs/foo"

exitcode, output = list_packages(prefix)
print('\n'.join(map(text_type, output)))
```

Note that this code is prone to break, since it is using internals.

**Signature**

```python
>>> help(list_packages)

# Help on function list_packages in module conda.cli.main_list:
list_packages(prefix, regex=None, format='human', show_channel_urls=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using -

```
help('modules')
```

in interactive mode.
( It works in cpython.)

Comment: Doesn't this only capture Python packages? Conda environments often contain more than just Python, e.g., compiled dependencies.